# Oracle 12c - cyrillic characters in CLOB field

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c, cyrillic

Tried different options, but until now there is no decisions.

Still, maybe someone faced - even just trying to create a table with a single `CLOB` field `(CL8MSWIN1251 and AL16UTF16)` - insert the text in cyrillic and it automatically converted to unreadable characters.

This is precisely the 12 version of the database.

Interestingly, in the documentation of `CHAR, VARCHAR2, CLOB` rely on database character `(CL8MSWIN1251 and AL16UTF16)` - however, the cyrillic text is displayed normally in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` fields but not in `CLOB`

Comment: Work through sql developer 17.2 - in preferences NLS set RUSSIAN

Comment: Try on 11 version with some character sets - and it's OK. But need 12 :(

Answer (score 1):

Find this ticket fro oracle support https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2366969_1.html
Try downgrade to 12.1.0 from 12.2 and it's OK